# Can't cast dictionary value to Array<String>

Tags: ios7, swift, ios8, xcode6

```
var mContent: Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, AnyObject>>;
...
let lContent = mContent["tabbar"] as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>;
let lTabBarItemsTitles = lContent["itemTitles"] as Array<String>;
```

Xcode shows a compile error on second line, which tells: `'String' is not convertible to Dictionary<String, AnyObject>`

`lContent["itemTitles"]` is an `Array<String>` . Why does Xcode show this error and how to get that `Array` from `Dictionary` ?

Comment: How is mContent declared?

Comment: var mContent: Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, AnyObject>>;

Comment: Don't use the semicolon. Don't cast the mContent["tabbar"] to `Dictionary<String, AnyObject>` it's already explicitly of that type. Try `let lContent = mContent["tabbar"]`

Comment: it doesn't work, it shows an error: '[String: AnyObject]? does not have a member named subscript' at the line : let lTabBarItemsTitles = lContent["itemTitles"] as Array<String>;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the `subscript` in `Dictionary` returns an optional:

```
subscript (key: KeyType) -> ValueType?
```

Meaning you have to unwrap the optional before you can downcast:

```
let lContent = mContent["tabbar"]! as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
let lTabBarItemsTitles = lContent["itemTitles"]! as Array<String>
```

As of Beta 3 you can access the value directly without downcasting, like this:

```
let lContent = mContent["tabbar"]!
let lTabBarItemsTitles = lContent["itemTitles"]
```

However I would suggest you wrap it around an if-let to make sure you don't unwrap nil values.

Comment: thanks, you are right. I missed the thing that subscript in Dictionary returns an optional value